# HTTP POST request in the Spring RESTful app

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I work with a `Spring RESTful` app and tries to do a `POST` request. It posts the data, but, when I tried to `GET` it back, the data format seems not in the correct format. The method is provided below,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
@Produces({"text/plain", "application/xml", "application/json"})
public class WalletRestController {

    @Autowired
    private WalletService walletService;

@PostMapping("/generateAddress")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> generateAddress(@RequestBody String walletName,
                                                UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder) {

        System.out.println("Creating wallet with name = " + walletName);

        if (walletName == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }

        walletService.generateAddress(walletName);

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
//      httpHeaders.setLocation(uriComponentsBuilder.path("/wallets/{id}").buildAndExpand(walletInfo.getId()).toUri());            

return new ResponseEntity<Void>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }

    }
```

The `POST` request in `Curl`,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"mikiii"}' http://localhost:8080/rest/generateAddress
```

I get the data using the `GET`,

```
[
  // more data  
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "{\"name\":\"mikiii\"}",
    "address": "mvmHyU1k6qkoUEpM9CQg4kKTzQ5si3oR1e"
  }
]
```

If I use only a `String`,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '"muuul"' http://localhost:8080/rest/generateAddress
```

I get it back as

```
[
// ........., 
{
    "id": 17,
    "name": "\"muuul\"",
    "address": "mr9ww7vCUzvXFJ6LDAz6YHnHPsd9kgYfox"
  }
]
```

This is the inner implementation of the `generateAddress` method `(I have the same name, should have changed)` create a new `WalletInfo` entity and currently returns `void`,

```
   @Override
    public synchronized void generateAddress(final String walletName) {

        WalletInfo walletInfo = walletInfoDao.getByName(walletName);

        // generate wallet, if the wallet is not
        // generated previously
        if (walletInfo == null) {

            if (genWalletMap.get(walletName) == null) {
                final WalletManager walletManager = WalletManager.setupWallet(walletName);
                walletManager.addWalletSetupCompletedListener((wallet) -> {
                    Address address = wallet.currentReceiveAddress();
                    WalletInfo newWallet = createWalletInfo(walletName, address.toString());

                    walletMangersMap.put(newWallet.getId(), walletManager);
                    genWalletMap.remove(walletName);
                });
                genWalletMap.put(walletName, walletManager);

                // return walletInfo;
            }
        }

        // return null;
    }
```

Currently, the `generateAddress` returns `void`. Earlier, I tried to return the `WalletInfo` from the method and set the location using the code, 
     `httpHeaders.setLocation(uriComponentsBuilder.path("/wallets/{id}").buildAndExpand(walletInfo.getId()).toUri());`

I get an error and this seems not working. I can provide that error stack if necessary, but, now again I return the `void` from the method in the current code.

In the `RESTful` method level, I have tried with `@PathVariable("name") String walletName` and `String walletName`. Obvously, this didn't help out 
and provided errors.

`UPDATE`

The `GET` method handlers with the `Curl` request are provided below,

```
// curl -G http://localhost:8080/rest/wallets | json

@RequestMapping(value = "/wallets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<WalletInfo>> getAllWalletInfo() {

     List<WalletInfo> walletInfos = walletService.getAllWallets();

    if (Objects.isNull(walletInfos)) {
       return new ResponseEntity<List<WalletInfo>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
     }
     return new ResponseEntity<List<WalletInfo>>(walletInfos, 
 HttpStatus.OK);
```

}

```
// curl -G http://localhost:8080/rest/wallets/1 | json

@RequestMapping(value = "/wallets/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<WalletInfo> getWalletById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

    System.out.println("Get wallet info with Id = " + id);

    WalletInfo walletInfo = walletService.getWalletInfo(id);

    if (walletInfo == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfo>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfo>(walletInfo, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How to get the address in the clean `String` like `"name": "testuser"` and have a proper `POST` request?

Comment: post your get method handler and how are you sending get request by curl

Comment: I have provided the get handlers with the `cURL` requests. Cna provided more info if required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are returning WalletInfo as a response entity getWalletById ().

```
return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfo>(walletInfo, HttpStatus.OK);
```

So this WalletInfo will be converted by jackson mapper and the corresponding fields in WalletInfo will be returned as a json object. I am guessing you have id, name and address fields in you WalletInfo class.
If you only want to return a subset of these fields like , name and address, then create a wrapper class like

```
public class WalletInfoWrapper {
   String name;
   String address;
  .. //gettter , setter
}
```

And return the object of this class from your handler , so your new code of get method handler will look like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/wallets/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper > getWalletById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

    System.out.println("Get wallet info with Id = " + id);

    WalletInfo walletInfo = walletService.getWalletInfo(id);

    if (walletInfo == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfo>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
   WalletInfoWrapper walletInfoWrapper = new WalletInfoWrapper ();
walletInfoWrapper.setName(walletInfo.getName());
walletInfoWrapper.setAddress(walletInfo.getAddress());
    return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper >(walletInfoWrapper , HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If you just want the address then your wrapper can have only address field.
Plus if you are bothered about the "\" before each double quotes, that is because you are redirecting the output from the rest call to a json utility

```
curl -G http://localhost:8080/rest/wallets/1 | json
```

, You can see the plain output by just

```
curl -G http://localhost:8080/rest/wallets/1
```

Comment: Works if I make the request like `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "nonald" http://localhost:8080/rest/generateAddress`.It returns the clear `String`